# Система смены пароля пользователя на MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю меню смены пароля пользователя на MySQL. В принципе все работает, но если я указываю что бы оно меняло на то что ввёл пользователь в input, то оно просто меняет на пустой пароль. При нажатии на кнопку запускается JS, и если пароли сходятся он запускает файл php. Вот пример кода:

```
<?PHP header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "login";
  $num1 = $_POST["pas1"];
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  $sql = "REPLACE INTO user VALUES
            (1, 'admin', '$num1', 'Ира')";
  if ($conn->query($sql)=== TRUE){
    echo "Record updeyted";
  }
  $conn->close();
?>

А это html:

        <form class="pas"  method="post">
          <h1>Смена пароля аккаунта</h1>
          <input id="num1"type="password" name="pas1" placeholder="Введите пароль">
          <input id="num2"type="password" name="pas2" placeholder="Повторите пароль">
          <input onclick="pas()"id="butt" type="button" name="but" value="Сменить!">
```

Answer (score 0):

Смену пароля лучше производить следующим запросом

```
ALTER USER 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';
```

Comment: Спасибо! Уже решил!